# Two external hdd but one does not get recognized

Tags: hardware, usb, hard-drive

I have two HDD on my ubuntu machine. One is a maxtor 320Gb and the other is a verbatim 1.5Tb. While it automatically recognizes the first one as sdb1 it doesn't recognize the latter. I can't see it on fdisk either.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Forgot to mention that is an USB with NTFS filesystem.

Comment: Does it have a filesystem on it?

Comment: What interface does it use? USB, eSATA? When attaching it, does it appear in the `dmesg` output?

Comment: @Kees It doesn't appear in the dmesg output.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in /dev/ or dmesg, it may be a hardware issue. Check the connections, and make sure everything's all right...

Comment: Works fine on windows. I don't know what the issue is, I tried all USB ports. The USB ports all work. My mouse is on USB as well.

Comment: If it's not appearing in the dmesg or a /dev/sd?? isn't showing, then it's certainly a very deep issue. If it's not hardware, then it's time to console yourself with a drink because it's not going to work.

Comment: How is the USB HDD powered?

Answer (score 2):

try `fdisk -l` and then `fdisk -l /dev/sdx` to make sure you know which device it is, not much you can do if it turns out it really isn't showing up in /dev/
try a different usb port?

Answer (score 1):

Post the output of dmesg

Can you mount your secondary harddisk manually.

Try to mount manually,let me know if it solves your problem

sudo mkdir /mnt/test && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/test

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single 1.5 TB partition? PLease post the output of dmesg as only then can anyone here help you.

sometimes you have to force a mount because ubuntu wont mount unclean ntfs filesystem

sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/test -o force